# Button resizing changing all design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I a creating a button using three divs and all divs have background images. This is how it looks like.

[Button Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ghx80Lgs/)

The button is fine but how can i resize it ?? I am doing like

```
.btncontainer{
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    left:120px; cursor:pointer;
     display:inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:20px;
}
```

But it is changing the button design. What can i do to resize it dynamically with the text?

i want to look like this if the size is changed for example this image  has different sizes.

[image: Sample sizes]

So when i changing the `.btncontainer` then it should change the width and height of the elements inside it but this is not happening

Comment: you should not use image. use colors.

Comment: i have to use images thats the requirement

Comment: Is the text part of the image? If it is, you can't prevent it getting squashed when the image is re-sized. You would need to create a background image for the button with no text on it. Then you can re-size the button with the background showing and control the look of the text seperately.

Comment: you can check this http://jsfiddle.net/xwrvxser/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you precised in an upper comment; In this special case, you have to use images for left and right divs. I suggest you to set a proper height to them, in the html code. 
This is not the best practise, but will do the work regarding your needs.
Please see the following example.

Please note you will have to change the `#backgrounddiv` height and line-height to match.

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ghx80Lgs/31/)

CSS

```
.btncontainer{
  position:absolute;
  top:180px;
  left:10px; cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}

#leftdiv{
  float:left;
}

#backgrounddiv{
  background:url("http://i.share.pho.to/0ffe9c14_o.png") top center repeat-x;
  float:left;
  height:40px;
  padding:10px;

  line-height:40px;
}

#rightdiv{
   float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="btncontainer" id="button">
  <a href="#">
    <div id='leftdiv'>
      <img src="http://i.share.pho.to/ff6cc4e3_o.png" height="70px" />
    </div>
    <div id='backgrounddiv'>CLick Me </div>
    <div id='rightdiv'>
      <img src="http://i.share.pho.to/245be416_o.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one is good but i can not move the button? its at 0,0 i am changing top:120px;  in btncontainer but still showing at 0px

Comment: Oops, sorry @user3754676. You should replace `position:absolute;` to your `btncontainer` ;) See http://jsfiddle.net/ghx80Lgs/33/

Comment: oh ok one more think if i define height:60px into my css then it is not working but only working if it is in the div    <div id='leftdiv'><img src="http://i.share.pho.to/ff6cc4e3_o.png" height="60px" />

Comment: At this point, you could set your image as an `background-image` property to your `leftdiv` and `rightdiv` and set its height and width (width will be important here).

Comment: You can take a look at this cool W3S article about `background-image` :) -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp